# i unchecked wireless and now its grayed out cant tun it back on

Tags: wireless, lan

so had a brain fart unchecked WiFi now its grayed out cant reconnect to WiFi
soft no
hard no 
tied network manager network all settings i could find and Google it and nobody has the same problem that i can find tried fn-f2 nothing

Answer (score 0):

Use `rfkill` (`rfkill - tool for enabling and disabling wireless devices`). Read `man rfkill` for instructions.